# Is there a function to simulate data from a robust linear regression or quantile regression model?

Tags: r, simulation, quantile-regression

Are there any functions that can simulate the response variable from a robust linear model or a quantile regression model like there is for linear models (i.e. `stats::simulate.lm`)?

If not, is there a way to adapt code to do this for either model?

Here is an example of the kind of data and models I am dealing with:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Response = c(1:30 + rnorm(n = 30)), Covariate =  c(seq(from = 10, to = 1.3, by = -0.3)))

#Robust linear regression
fit.rlm <- MASS::rlm(Response ~ Covariate, data = df)

#Quantile regression
fit.qr <- quantreg::rq(Response ~ Covariate, data = df, tau = c(0.025,0.5,0.975)
```

Comment: See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/vignettes/lmrob_simulation.pdf. There are a few different kinds of assumption violations that robust models are supposed to protect against, so you need to think about which ones you want to account for.

Comment: I didn't realise I needed to say that I have thoroughly searched with both google and within stackoverflow/cross-validated. I have and I found absolutely nothing - I will make sure to put that at the fore-front in the future. I don't know enough about coding to alter the `stats::simulate` function. As I said at the beginning of my question - I am aiming to simulate a response.

Comment: @Marius the above comment was directed at 42-, who seems to have deleted his comment.